# how can I install google chrome as my default browser in windows 10 with microsoft edge

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have anew laptop with windows 10,it opens with microsoft edge, I have always used google chrome but cannot find a way to install as default browser

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Chrome - Settings - Set as default. When opening something in IE/Edge - cancel reset when asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed chrome on your windows 10 laptop:
- Open Settings
- Click Apps
- On the left menu choose Default Apps
- Scroll down to Web Browser
- Click the current default one and choose chrome.

If you have not installed chrome:
- Download google chrome from here:
  https://www.google.com/chrome/
- Install it and then when it starts it will itself ask you to make it your 
  default browser, if it does not then follow the steps above.